# Anchor tag page jump

Tags: html, anchor

This should be a simple one: I have a page with a bunch of named anchor tags. These tags are linked to from various other pages on the site. But for some reason, when I link to the page#anchor, it always jumps back to the top. For example:

http://thedenvillehub.com/test-hs/services.asp#firesetter

It goes to the correct area, but then jumps to the top.

Same thing happens if you click on a link to get to it:

http://thedenvillehub.com/test-hs/troubled.asp (click on "Juvenile Firesetter Program")

Any ideas? It works correctly in IE, but not FF or Chrome.

Comment: Do you have any javascript that executes on page load or DOM ready? If so, that may be the issue.

Answer (score 5):

You have in-line JS that's causing this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// When ready...
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
    // Set a timeout...
    setTimeout(function(){
        // Hide the address bar!
        window.scrollTo(0, 1);
    }, 0);
});
</script>
```

Comment: that worked, thanks. i was using that for mobile phones to hide the address bar, but this is more important :)

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the following JavaScript:

```
// When ready...
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
    // Set a timeout...
    setTimeout(function(){
        // Hide the address bar!
        window.scrollTo(0, 1);
    }, 0);
});
```

Removing this script should solve your issue.